# Using Facebook like box with language targeted posts

Tags: facebook, facebook-likebox

I included the Facebook Like Box on a website I developed.

```
<div id="facebook-likebox-holder">
    <div id="fb-root"></div>
    <script>(function (d, s, id) {
        var js, fjs = d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0];
        if (d.getElementById(id)) return;
        js = d.createElement(s); js.id = id;
        js.src = "//connect.facebook.net/<%= GetLabel("fbLocale") %>/all.js#xfbml=1&appId=XXXXXXXXXXXXXX";
        fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js, fjs);
    }(document, 'script', 'facebook-jssdk'));</script>
    <div class="fb-like-box" data-href="http://www.facebook.com/MYFBPAGE" data-colorscheme="light" data-show-faces="false" data-header="false" data-stream="true" data-show-border="false"></div>
</div>
```

My GetLabel("fbLocale") will either return "fr_CA" or "en_CA" depending on the language settings of my website. We also manage the client's Facebook page and since it has both French and English audiences, we adjust all the posts we do, targeting English or French accordingly.

Now when I look at the Like Box on the website, weather I'm on the French or English site, I see both posts (FR and EN) in the Like Box's post stream.

The language of the social plugin does correctly change.

I tried looking at the Like Box logged into Facebook (with my English (US) locale and with the local set to French (CA)) and also while being logged out, but still, I always see both types of posts.

Has anyone managed to have the language specific posts to be filtered appropriately in theLike Box?

Thanks for the help!